# Closed laptop uses laptop screen a few hours after closing rather than plugged in monitors only

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display

I generally use my laptop while closed and connected to a couple of external monitors. I adjusted the power settings choosing to "do nothing" when lid is closed.

When I close the lid for the first time, it works as expected and I only am using my 2 plugged in monitors. After a few hours though (even if I leave it plugged in with lid close), it will revert to using all 3 monitors (the 3rd one being the laptop screen). Of course I cant see the screen because it is closed.

I need to manually open and close the laptop so that it goes back to only using the external monitors.

Is there a way to stop this from happening or to manually check the closed status and only use the plugged in monitors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I generally use my laptop while closed and connected to a couple of
> external monitors. I adjusted the power settings choosing to "do
> nothing" when lid is closed.

Do Nothing may be a cause of this issue, because the laptop is doing nothing and the monitor accordingly can be used.

I have worked a lot with this setup with customers.

Best approach:  Get a proper dock for your laptop.  Put it on the dock OFF and lid closed.  Power it up and your monitor should stay off.

Depending on your laptop, you may need to set Lid Close to normal (that is, close the Lid suspends the machine). Try it with Do Nothing as it is and see if it works in the dock and change the setting as necessary.